# Mongo db trying to create restorable backup

Tags: mongodb

I got databse with name "test" in mongoatlas.
I installed mongodb with

```
mongodb-windows-x86_64-4.4.1-signed.msi
```

I run this command and it does not shows my test db. I'm trying to make backup my db

```
show dbs

admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

I watched tutorial to how to backup&restore in mongodb. So I  run the command

```
mongodump
```

It says

```
'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

but I can run mongo and mongod command. I gave a path to run mongodb in cmd to environment variables
[image: Mongo and mongodump in CMD]
Also they say in the docs use mongodump command in cmd. I tryed it with administrator mode and it still gives same think.
So how can I backup& restore dbs. Thank you
[image: The downloaded and extracted zip file]
[image: The installed path with ".exe" setup]

Answer (score 2):

`mongodump` is part of the [mongo database tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/#the-mongodb-database-tools-documentation), these tools are not automatically installed when your install certain Mongo server bundles.
As in your case, your cmd line does not recognise this command because it was never installed on your machine.

Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/#the-mongodb-database-tools-documentation) in order to install it.

> 1. Access the [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools)
> 2. Select your Platform from the dropdown menu, then select the following Package for your platform:
> 3. Once downloaded, unpack the archive and copy the tools to a location on your hard drive.

Comment: Yes I made it exactly like this but, I added the screenshots to my intalled folders

Comment: Now I get it, I installed another zip file database tools.Mongodump command is working now but It still does not shows the my test db

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the MongoDB install path in your `Path` environment variables
For eg :
My mongoDB is installed at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`

In environment variables i should have,[image]

[image: Also here]

Also make sure you have installed mongodb properly. You should have following set of exe/files

[image: Mongo Files]

Comment: Yes as I mentioned I added both path variable in  environment variables

Comment: Looks like you are missing files in setup. Your setup looks incomplete. See updated answer

Comment: How can I complete installiation, I ran setup which is downloaded from mongodb website

Comment: I downloaded here https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server